# npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /builds/sab-management/ui-v3/node_modules/node-sass

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gitlab, node-modules, node-sass

When I commit and push my code, when I want to merge request, I get this error in the pipelines and the branch fails.
I checked and updated all my project packages, committed and pushed again, ran pipelines again, but failed again!؟

```
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /builds/sab-management/ui-v3/node_modules/node-sass
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
   npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
    
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-25T11_49_52_514Z-debug.log
   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Getting an error in pipelines after pushing the merge request code in git lap

Answer (score 0):

error is from local server and it started when the install got an error. Do a trace back on the log and see exactly where "npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).